# MS Access Project 2007 SP3 slow performance

Tags: ms-access, sql-server-2008-r2, adp

I have a project built on MS Access project and There is a strange slow performance issue on MS Access 2007 SP3

I track this issue on two machines that are:

1. Windows 7 - 64 bit
2. Microsoft Office Access 2007 (12.0.6606.1000) SP3 MSO (12.0.6607.1000)
3. SQL SERVER 2008 R2
4. SQL SERVER Driver (oledb.dll) Version 6.01.7601.17514

There is no difference between two PCs that I try to test but there is obvious slow performance when I open the same screen (I watch SQL SERVER Profiler and I noticed that same query takes 4 sec on first environment and takes 1.5 minute on second environment, and also the Reads column on profiler give a big number for the slow query)

The query is:

> SELECT MReceiveNumber, [Line Number], [Item Number],      ROW_NUMBER()
>   OVER (ORDER BY [Line Number]) -
>   dbo.GetPrevMRQryLinesCount(MReceiveNumber, [Line Number]) AS Serial
>   FROM tblMReceiveItems

Note: This query takes 2.20 minutes in SQL SERVER Management

So, Is there any performance issue with access 2007 SP3 or there are other things that I should do/review?

Thank you for help.

Comment: Could you possibly post the query? What happens when you copy paste into SSMS and run? Remember when copy/pasting, include all the SET options. it might be parameter sniffing

Comment: I guess `dbo.GetPrevMRQryLinesCount` is a UDF? They are always red flags for performance, though it doesn't explain why one is fast and one isn't.

Comment: You are right about that it's slow in SQL SERVER Management, but MS Access execute same query fast about 4 sec in the first environment and slow about 1.2 minute in the second enviornment

Comment: I can enhance the query and make it run fast but I just want to know, why same two environment settings have big different performance?

Comment: When comparing the two queries in profiler, take special note of all the SET options which occur beforehand. Please take time to confirm they are identical.

Comment: To see whether it is parameter sniffing, and assuming this is not a production server, do the following: 1. Run `DBCC FREEPROCCACHE` in SSMS; 2. Now run the _slow_ PC - is it still slow or fast?

Comment: This statement effect on DB Server or just the tested database

Comment: It has an effect on the whole server. Google can tell you. It's just one way of testing